# React has no exported member LinkHTMLAttributes

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, visual-studio-2017

I am building a react application using vs2017 , npm and webpack.

I can't get vs to build my solution because of the error described in my title:

> Error TS2694  Build:Namespace 'React' has no exported member
>   'LinkHTMLAttributes'. SpyStore.React  C:\Work\Development\React\Spystore\SpyStore.React\SpyStore.React\node_modules\@types\react-router\lib\Link.d.ts 10

Js File : \node_modules\@types\react-router\lib\Link.d.ts

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Router from './Router';

declare const Link: Link;
type Link = Link.Link;

export default Link;

declare namespace Link {
    interface LinkProps extends React.LinkHTMLAttributes<Link> {
        activeStyle?: React.CSSProperties;
        activeClassName?: string;
        onlyActiveOnIndex?: boolean;
        to: Router.RoutePattern | Router.LocationDescriptor | ((...args: any[]) => Router.LocationDescriptor);
    }

    interface Link extends React.ComponentClass<LinkProps> {}
    interface LinkElement extends React.ReactElement<LinkProps> {}
}
```

These are the dependencies and devdependencies inside my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "jquery": "3.1.1",
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "15.4.2",
    "react-router": "3.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "1.10.31",
    "@types/react": "0.0.0",
    "@types/react-router": "^2.0.41",
    "typescript": "2.1.6",
    "tslint": "4.4.2",
    "webpack": "2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "1.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.3.0",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "0.0.5",
    "webpack-merge": "2.6.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.0.4-rc.2",
    "url-loader": "0.5.7",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "ts-loader": "2.0.0",
    "ts-node": "2.1.0",
    "tslint-loader": "3.3.0",
    "open-browser-webpack-plugin": "0.0.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "0.10.0",
    "html-loader": "0.4.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.28.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "0.3.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.0.1",
    "source-map-loader": "0.1.6"
  }
```

I have tried to delete my node_modules and install them again.

Without success.
Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I have one more build error: (react-router/lib/withRouter)
`Error TS2314 Build:Generic type 'PureComponent<P, S>' requires 2 type argument(s). `

Comment: Above error got solved aswell, updating my react-router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, clearly I didn't search long enough.. Impatient me..

My visual studio didn't show any intellisense on the error, but after some trying I only had to update my react-router to a newer version ;)